# meteor mongo update spliced array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, modifier

I'm currently working on a function which generates an mongodb modifier object based on an orginal object and an changed object.
The goal is to update the document as carefully as possible. *(only changes will be added to the modifier)*

Changed objects (which may be nested) work just fine. But I'm having issues with arrays:

If I take an array `[1,2,3,4]` and run `arr.splice(1,1)`, the array looks like this: `[1,3,4]`. This is correct.

The problem is the following:
When I compare `[1,2,3,4]` to `[1,3,4]` my function would change the indexes 1 and 2 and then remove the 3rd index since its not needed anymore.
The generated modifier would look like this:

```
//document in collection
{
  arr: [1,2,3,4]
}

//generated modifier
{
  $set: {
    'arr.1': 3,
    'arr.2': 4
  },
  $push: {
    $slice: 3
  }
}
```

This produces the following error:
`MongoError: Cannot update 'arr.1' and 'arr' at the same time`

Do you have any suggestions how to remove this last index within *one* query?
Or do I *have* to use multiple updates to archive this?

Comment: Why not use `$pull` for that: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/ ?

Comment: @Jankapunkt what should be the condition for `$pull` then?